# Your assistance is always appreciated

Tags: passive-voice

I need to praise my PhD supervisors kind assistance. Can I use the sentence of 'your assistance is always appreciated' for that. I doubt that whether it is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Your assistance is always appreciated" is a perfectly acceptable sentence. Depending on the context, you could also use "I always appreciate your assistance". The former is more professional, but the latter emphasises your level of appreciation.